# C++ nested class error "cannot convert ... in assignment"

Tags: c++, class, nested

I'm new to C++ and I keep getting this error message in the following class:

```
class LinkedList {

    class Node *head;

    class Node {
        Student *student;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
    public:
        Node(Student *n_student, Node *n_next, Node *n_prev);
        ~Node();

        Student *getStudent() const;
        Node *getNext() const;
        Node *getPrev() const;
    };

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void printList();
};
```

The method that causes the error:

```
void LinkedList::printList() {
    using namespace std;

    class Node *p_n;
    p_n = head; // ERROR!

    while (p_n) {
        cout << '[' << (*(*p_n).getStudent()).getId() << ']' << endl;
        p_n = (*p_n).getNext();
    }
}
```

The error message I'm getting is

> error: cannot convert 'Node*' to
>   'LinkedList::Node*' in assignment

I've tried casting Node to LinkedList::Node but I keep getting the same message. I'm compiling it in Xcode, not sure if that causes the problem.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: +1 For a well-asked homework question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
class Node *head;
```

Into this:

```
Node *head;
```

When you declare a field of a certain class inside a class, you don't need the `class` keyword. Just the type name and its corresponding identifier. Like this:

```
Node *n;
LinkedList *l;
```

No `class` keyword. `class` keyword is only used when you actually declare/define a class.

Comment: I've tried this before posting the q on SO, but I get the same error message.

Comment: This gives me another error message: *error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Node' with no type*. Do you know what might cause that?

Comment: Oh sorry, I placed *Node *head;* before the class definition itself. Corrected it and now it finally compiles! Thank you!!